# Multi-site manager Channel Images

Tags: multi-site-manager, error, channel-images, act

I'm having a Multi-site manager setup and am using Channel Images as image upload.

On the first site, everything goes well. Let's call it www.firstwebsite.com

The images are uploaded to `/server/firstwebsite/uploads/`.

The other one, www.secondwebsite.com, doesn't work that well. Via the admin, I can not upload images in channel images.

Console tells me this: `http://www.secondwebsite.be/?ACT=44&ajax_method=upload_file&field_id=96&key=1434980450 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

Channel images keeps spinning and says: `NaN%`.

Although, when I go to firstwebsite via the link in the top right (so I'm editing website two with firstwebsite.com/admin.php, the uploading works BUT it's uploaded to the wrong folder. So `/server/firstwebsite/uploads/` rather then `/server/secondwebsite/uploads/`.

Someone has experience with this? If so, please help. It's an urgent matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupidly, nothing was wrong with my settings, but with how the subdomain was linked to the url on the server. It had been linked to second-website, rather than secondwebsite. I overlooked that, as everything else worked, expect upload destinations.